# jasperreport server scheduling with today's date

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm trying to set up a report using the scheduler with today's date as the input parameter.  Is this possible?

I see you can set static value for the input parameter but cannot set it to now() or some variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

report parameter name is $P{Date}

I've set the default expression to

```
($P{Date} == null ? new Date() : $P{Date})
```

And it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Sam, in your report, could you create a parameter with a default value of today's date (see Filtering on a Date Range: http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Jasperserver/Filtering_on_a_date_range)? Then make it mandatory so JasperReports Server will choose the default value if no other input is given.

Comment: I do have a default parameter set to "new Date()" in the jrxml but when I go to schedule it.. I leave the parameter blank (null) hoping the default will pick up.  But null propagates through instead.